# NullPointerException in AutoCompleteRenderer

Tags: primefaces, autocomplete, nullpointerexception

I create AutoComplete component programmatically use next Java API:

```
public class AutoCompleteHandler extends UIComponentHandler<AutoComplete> {
@Override
public AutoComplete handle(AutoComplete component, Map<String, String> attributes) {
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Application application = ctx.getApplication();

    component.setId(attributes.get(InspectionResultConstants.NAME));

    String elExpression = FacesUtils.wrapExpression("addressFinder.getAddressList");
    MethodExpression methodExpression = application.getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(ctx.getELContext(), elExpression, List.class, new Class<?>[]{String.class});
    component.setCompleteMethod(methodExpression);

    return component;
}
```

}

My bean which realize method for introducing list of String for AutoComplete Component:

```
    @Named
    @ViewScoped
    public class AddressFinder implements Serializable {
    private String addressValue;
    private ArrayList<String> selections = new ArrayList<>();
    private String uIComponentName;

    public String getAddressValue() {
        return addressValue;
    }

    public void setAddressValue(String addressValue) {
        this.addressValue = addressValue;
    }

    public void setUIComponentName(String name) {
        this.uIComponentName = name;
    }

    public List<String> getAddressList(String searchStr) throws SQLException {
        AddressFinderUtils.recalculateSelections(selections, searchStr);
        Client client = AddressFinderUtils.getClient();
        int phase = selections.size();
        String idexName = AddressFinderUtils.getESIndexNameBySearchPhase(phase, this.uIComponentName);
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(idexName)) return null;
        String typeName = AddressFinderUtils.getESTypeNameBySearchPhase(phase, this.uIComponentName);
        String esQuery = AddressFinderUtils.getQueryBySearchPashe(phase, selections,  searchStr, this.uIComponentName);


        SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(idexName)
                .setTypes(typeName)
                .setExtraSource(esQuery)
                .setFetchSource(true).setFrom(0).setSize(10)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();

        String ESSourceFieldName = AddressFinderUtils.getESSorceFieldNameBySearchPhase(phase, this.uIComponentName);
        if (ESSourceFieldName == null) return null;

        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        String resStr;
        for (SearchHit searchHit : response.getHits()) {
            resStr = searchHit.sourceAsMap().get(ESSourceFieldName).toString();
            results.add(resStr);
        }

        return results;
    }

    public void onItemSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        selections.add(event.getObject().toString());
    }
}
```

When I imput some text into AutoComponent on some view into log I see next  stack trace:

> 17:41:45,822 SEVERE
>   [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default
>   task-111) java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeSuggestionsAsList(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:516)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeSuggestions(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:411)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeResults(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:122)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeEnd(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:104)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:582)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1689)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.api.UITabPanel.visitTree(UITabPanel.java:920)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)

In debug mode I look that my method return some List of String it is not null, but into method `org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer#encodeResults` comes UIComponent with `suggestions = null`. But if  I set break point into method `org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoComplete#broadcast` I see that invoket and suggestion sets from my method `AddressFinder.getAddressList()`.

I noticed that a instance of  AutoComplete when correctly sets suggesions and instance of  AutoComplete which is supplied to the method encodeResults different.

```
Primefaces version is 5.2
```

Comment: I am not sure whether you and I have the same problem here. I got NullPointerException when my bean is annotated by ViewScoped. After I changed to RequestScoped, everything seems worked.

Comment: I got the same exception in my p:autocomplete when using update="@form", then I've changed to update="componentA componentB" and worked back again. Hope it helps.